# KnockoutJS newly added element does not have any styling from the stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm trying to use KnockOut, similar to this page: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html

However, when used with the JQuery Mobile theme - when you select an item from the Category drop down, it then adds a drop down list under the Product heading - BUT the second dropdown just added, doesn't have the mobile styling applied.

I've added a Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtait/adNuR/1927/ - to demonstrate.
What can I add that will add the styling to the new drop down list?

```
function formatCurrency(value) {
return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
}

var CartLine = function() {
var self = this;
self.category = ko.observable();
self.product = ko.observable();
self.quantity = ko.observable(1);
self.subtotal = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.product() ? self.product().price * parseInt("0" + self.quantity(), 10) : 0;
});

// Whenever the category changes, reset the product selection
self.category.subscribe(function() {
    self.product(undefined);
});
};

var Cart = function() {
// Stores an array of lines, and from these, can work out the grandTotal
var self = this;
self.lines = ko.observableArray([new CartLine()]); // Put one line in by default
self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $.each(self.lines(), function() { total += this.subtotal() })
    return total;
});

// Operations
self.addLine = function() { self.lines.push(new CartLine()) };
self.removeLine = function(line) { self.lines.remove(line) };
self.save = function() {
    var dataToSave = $.map(self.lines(), function(line) {
        return line.product() ? {
            productName: line.product().name,
            quantity: line.quantity()
        } : undefined
    });
    alert("Could now send this to server: " + JSON.stringify(dataToSave));
};
};

ko.applyBindings(new Cart());
```

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14256674/419956) may be of help to you.

Comment: Hi Jereon - thank you - that was one of my posts too, but I couldn't get the .trigger to work - I've added to the example above.

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't noticed the other question was yours as well.

Comment: I've tried to take a second look at your question, but I can't get your code to work. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CmUvH/) where I've *tried* to make your code into a repro. Please clean your code by removing all things irrelevant to the question (they make your question very hard to read for outsiders), and also add any code needed to reproduce the issue. Ideally the code in your question is absolutely minimal and can be dropped in a fiddle environment instantly showing the issue.

Comment: Hi @Jeroen - I've added a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtait/adNuR/1926/ - if you click on Add Product, you can see the new drop down lists added, do not have mobile styling.  Thank you.

Comment: Updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtait/adNuR/1928/

Comment: I saw the comment that references your previous question after I posted my answer to this one.  I didn't investigate why triggering the event was not the solution before, but I think it works in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a customer binding handler.

Handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmOptions = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context);
        $(element).selectmenu();
        $(element).selectmenu("refresh", true);
    }
};
```

Binding:

```
<select data-bind='jqmOptions : sampleProductCategories, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: category'> </select>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adNuR/1942/

Comment: Hi @Dan - your fiddle doesn't add a second dropdown list when I select from the first one.  But I added the ID and the line you suggested above, to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtait/adNuR/1931/ - but when selecting something from the first drop down, the second drop down is added, however again, without styling.  The Add Product button works, as it runs the trigger part - but how do you add the trigger when a selection is made from the category drop down.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay enough attention to the question.  I updated my answer to address the problem when the category changes.

Comment: Updated the answer and fiddle again to use "Refresh" instead of "Create".

Comment: Glad to help.  I updated the answer to remove the stuff about the "create" event, so it will be easier to read for anyone in the future.